# Issue in bootstrap tooltip when bootstrap modal is a on-click event

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, tooltip

[I have a icon tooptip, ng-click event on the icon opens a bootstrap Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2arzF.jpg)

When I close the modal, the tooltip stuck on screen as shown in the image link . When second time I hover over and move my mouse out from the icon, then the tooltip is getting invisible.

I tried a lot to remove the tooltip after close of modal, did anyone faced the same issue. ?

Comment: can u show somecode...how your calling modal

Comment: `<button  type="button" class="btn btn-default tooltip-target" ng-click="closeAddUserForm()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddUserModal" title="Activate Users"><i class="icon-ico_male_lg"></i></button>`

Comment: `$('.tooltip-target').tooltip();` This is the Code in .controller of this page.

Comment: try this $('.tooltip-target').tooltip({
            trigger: 'hover'
        });

Comment: I tried to close the tooltip inside this event `$('#AddUserModal, #groupCreationModal, #createUserModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
       $('.tooltip-target').tooltip('dispose'); 
      });` But still facing the same issue

Comment: ok lemme try it

Comment: Wow man, its working... Thanks a lot.. can you please tell what was the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('.tooltip-target').tooltip();
```

with this tooltip getting focus again and

with the following you restricted the 
focus that will be show up only after a hover again

`$('.tooltip-target').tooltip({ trigger: 'hover' });`